# How to replace all "/" within a p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace all forward slashes within a p tag but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = $("p").text();
  content.replace(/\//g, 'ForwardSlash');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>YOYOYO / yoyoyoy / YIYYIYIYI ddwqd w/ dwdwdw/ dwd / dwd /</p>
<div>YOYOYO / yoyoyoy / YIYYIYIYI ddwqd w/ dwdwdw/ dwd / dwd /</div>
```

The reason that I want to do this is because a site I am making requires all the forward slashes to be a different colour to the text within the tag and as I am building the site within a CMS I am trying to make it easy to edit. The crude way of doing this would be to make the client paste spans with class names or inline styles. Hopefully I can do one of those things for him automatically using your help and the code above.

Comment: All you did was change a string named content. You need to then actually update the `p` tag's innerHTML with the new string.

Comment: @dman2306 You are right but its not the case here, as he has a div and a p and is using jauerys text, which does not return the element, just its textNode.

Comment: @somethinghere yeah. I misread and removed the comment already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. But, know that `replace()` does not take a string with a reference and modify it. Rather, it returns a result and you will have to use that result

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).text();

    content = content.replace(/\//g, 'ForwardSlash');
    $(this).text(content);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>YOYOYO / yoyoyoy / YIYYIYIYI ddwqd w/ dwdwdw/ dwd / dwd /</p>
<p>YOYOYO / yoyoyoy / YIYYIYIYI ddwqd w/ dwdwdw/ dwd / dwd /</p>
```

Comment: I'd recommend we consider using .html() not .text(). If this is a CMS its probably safe to assume the contents of a p tag may include html. Using text() we're stripping that away. Probably need clarification from the OP to know which is better.

Comment: I am doing it via custom fields so the client can only input into a text input.

Comment: @2ne , still, the client could use a `strong` tag to bolden some text and those would be stripped with `text()`

Comment: Ah yeh good point. What is the best way to replace 'ForwardSlash' with a span tag? Should I append that separately?

Comment: @dman2306, do you mean the OP might want the slashes in inner HTML itself removed?

Comment: @2ne just replace it with the string `<span>/</span>` and you're golden. You can even add classes etc... Again, use `html()` to reinsert the changed content and jQuery handles the rest.

Comment: @2ne, do you want the slashes in acual HTML removed also?

Comment: @AmmarCSE no I mean what if the content of the p tag is: `<p>this is my <b>html</b> inside my p with some / in it as well</p>` that is a bit trickier to deal with

Comment: content = content.replace(/\//g, 'ForwardSlash'); on this line i was trying to do this: content = content.replace(/\//g, '"<span class="white">/</span>'); but it renders the html tag in place

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to apply the result back to the `p` (and to the `content` variable, as `content` itself does not get modified, it **returns** the *modified string*, so you would have to reassign the result to `content` if you want to do it in multiple steps).

Also, as @dman2306 mentioned, it might be better to use `html()` instead of `text()` as any other nodes are stripped when using text, including `<em>` and `<strong>` tags, which are often used inside `<p>` tags. Although this would require a regex pattern to *not* remove any slashes that were preceded by a `<`...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = $("p").text().replace(/\//g, 'ForwardSlash');
  $("p").text(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>YOYOYO / yoyoyoy / YIYYIYIYI ddwqd w/ dwdwdw/ dwd / dwd /</p>
<div>YOYOYO / yoyoyoy / YIYYIYIYI ddwqd w/ dwdwdw/ dwd / dwd /</div>
```

Comment: var content = $("p").text().replace(/\//g, "<span class='white'>"/"</span>"); I get some weird results from this, returns NaN

Comment: @2ne you can't use `"<span class='white'>"/"</span>"`, as that `/` is an unescaped character that gets read as are trying to divide (`/`) a string by a string, resulting in `NaN` (not-a-number). Just use it as a part of the string itself:  `"<span class='white'>/</span>"`. jQuery will insert the string _as html_ and do everything else for you.

Comment: How to I get this code to insert the html rather than the text: var content = $("p").text().replace(/\//g, "<span class='white'>/</span>");

http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/LVxevR

Comment: Use `var content = $("p").text().replace(/\//g, "<span class='white'>/</span>"); $("p").html(content);` This will aissng the newly modified string to the var `content` and then insert the string as HTML code into the `p` tag.